# The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'Id'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I'm a newbie in MVC, so please help me to get out of this. I want to retrieve `NameofBike` in DB. I'm using LINQ for it, but something wrong in there.
My `Action`:

```
public ActionResult Index(int Id, string Name)
{
     // Create our view model  
    var viewModel = BikesDB.ProductSubcategories
        .Where(m => m.NameofBike == Name && m.ProductSubcategoryID == Id);

    return this.View(viewModel);
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class Bike
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

public class CategoriesIndexViewModel
{
    public int NumberOfModel { get; set; }
    public List<string> NameofBike { get; set; }
    public List<Bike> Bikes { get; set; }
}
```

When debugged it throws an error like this:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'Id' of
>   non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Int32, System.String)' in
>   'AdventureCycle.Controllers.BikeController'. An optional parameter
>   must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an
>   optional parameter.

Here's the navigate:

```
<ul id="navlist">
            <li>
                <a href="@Url.Content("~/Bike/")">Home</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="@Url.Content("~/Bike/Categories/1?name=Mountain Bikes&class=image")">Mountain Bikes</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="@Url.Content("~/Bike/Categories/2?name=Road Bikes&class=image")">Road Bikes</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="@Url.Content("~/Bike/Categories/3?name=Touring Bikes&class=image")">Touring Bikes</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

Comment: How do you call `Index` action? Do you pass `Id` into it?

Comment: I don't get it what do you mean? Did I pass `Id` above already?

Comment: Yes. You expect `Id` parameter in the `Index` action, do you pass it? How do you navigate to the `Index` action?

Comment: No I don't, `Index`action in Home Page when debug.

Answer (score 0):

I think you ID value contains some null value. try this links it may help you

[MVC 3 The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686528/mvc-3-the-parameters-dictionary-contains-a-null-entry-for-parameter-id-of-non)

[Parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893036/parameters-dictionary-contains-a-null-entry-for-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

Basically your Id parameter is missing from the form POST.

Put a breakpoint on your Index action method on the line:

```
 `var viewModel = Bikes....`
```

and run the project in debug.  When the breakpoint is hit, hover over the `int Id & string Name` params and you'll see what is actually being passed to your method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate urls via [UrlHelper.Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) method so they match you route configuration. Also you can create links via [LinkExtensions.ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Bike",
     new { Id = /* categoryId here */, Name = /* name of a bike */ })
```